# Ubuntu 22.04.3. "Google chrome" systematically fails to load the internet pages on the very first time I start the application

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Toshiba Satellite C55-A-1TX Laptop.

Since the very beginning, and each time I start my computer, I have the following behavior.

When I have started the laptop (power ON), **the very first time I run my Google Chrome application**, it keeps showing "Loading ... " on the multiple internet page tabs.

The only ways I found to make the pages appear are:

1. Go into Chrome, and on each tab, click and do a "F5" to refresh it.
2. Click on the top right "Cross" to close Google Chrome, and then click on the application icon to run it again.  Then, because it is no more the first time this application is started, everything is working fine.

Note : As I said before, it is since the very beginning I installed the computer.  It does not seem to be linked with any Ubuntu version and/or Google-Chrome version.
I mean I have always experienced the same issue, when I was before in Ubuntu version 20.04, and now the same with the last LTS version, in the meantime also remains the same with a lot of different Google-Chrome versions.

Question :

What can I do to get Google Chrome starting and loading the internet pages properly from the first start after powering on my computer?

Comment: Could anybody inform on what is different the first time you start an application, vs the all other following starts ?  Knowing this could probably help to better understand what is missing or does not pass during the first start.  Thank you !